# How do I mask a multi-layer netCDF or raster with a single-layer shapefile?

Tags: r, geospatial, netcdf, shapefile, r-raster

I am currently working with daily precipitation data in netCDF format. The data's at a 4km resolution that covers the United States. However, I want to mask/clip the data with a much higher-resolution shapefile for a particular geographical region (about the size of a county). Ultimately, I want the output to be daily precipitation data, either at that high resolution or the original 4km resolution, for the much smaller area.

I've tried a couple different methods, with the most success using the following code:

```
prcp_2000 <- raster::brick('pr_2000.nc')
shapefile <- shapefile("polygon_combined.shp")
shapefile <- spTransform(shapefile, crs(prcp_2000))
prcp_2000 <- mask(prcp_2000, shapefile)
prcp_2000 <- crop(prcp_2000, shapefile)
outfile <- paste("prcp_","2000_","CS",".nc",sep="")
writeRaster(prcp_2000, outfile, overwrite=TRUE, format="CDF", varname="prcp", varunit="mm/day", longname="mm of precipitation per day", xname="lon", yname="lat", zname="day", zunit="days since 1900-01-01")
```

However, I keep getting nothing but infinities/negative infinities for prcp output, even though I'm still getting appropriate variable lengths otherwise (day=366, lat=24, lon=23). Am I missing something?

Comment: Thanks for supplying code. However it looks like you didn't supply all the code, since you refer to `gridmet_prcp_2000` in your `spTransform`, but it's not clear where that object comes from.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out John! Fixed - this should have been prcp_2000 (I shortened the variable names here for simplicity).

Comment: Do you get the same output, other than extent, when you type `prcp_2000` after reading in the file and again after using `mask`? In other words, do you get the values that you expect in `prcp_2000` after masking? Is it just the file that you write out that has the problem with the wrong values? If it's just when you write the file, you might want to try using `datatype =` in the `writeRaster` call. You can read about `datatype` here: https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/raster/html/dataType.html  `raster` default: FLT4s. It would be helpful to have a sample of your netCDF and poly data.

Comment: It seems like it might be an issue with the CRS conversion! The extents don't match up (the prcp data is essentially CONUS, and the shapefile should be in Wisconsin but shows up in the Gulf of Mexico). Still not sure what the issue is - I've tried reading in the shapefile with shapefile(), readOGR(), vect(), but every conversion I've tried (like with spTransform() above) leads me to the same result. I've linked the data in a GitHub repo, let me know if this works: https://github.com/huntercmackin/Masking-Shapefile-R . Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the starting shapefile, `shapefile <- shapefile("polygon_combined.shp")`. I imported "polygon_combined.shp" into QGIS to plot a base layer under it easily. The image I've attached shows that it *starts off* in the Gulf of Mexico. With a bad location to begin with, transforming it isn't going to save it later.

[image: image of QGIS scene with AOI in Gulf of Mexico]

I don't know the origin of the data, so I have no idea how it was produced this way to start. One way to possibly fix this is get the data from a different source. The EPA makes an ecoregions product that has several levels of regions. I think you want the level IV data to get your region. You may still need to transform it, but it'll be located in the right place to begin with. https://www.epa.gov/eco-research/ecoregion-download-files-state-region-5#pane-47

Comment: Thank you so much! I was convinced this was an issue with the conversion to a new CRS. Thank you for the tip with the EPA ecoregions as well!